# unpacking variadic template arguments to define new template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I am new to template programming and I have two questions...Hopefully someone can help me.
I am trying to use variadic templates to generate a new input to another variadic template.
In other words, I have a class

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... M>
class Class1 {

}
```

I want to use the integer values represented by N,M to generate a new set of std::bitset type inputs to another templated class

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class Class2 {

}
```

So for example if I use `Class1<10,20,25>` I want inside the body of `Class1` to 
create a 
`Class2<std::bitset<10>, std::bitset<20>, std::bitset<25>>` 
variable. Is there a simple way to do this using C++11?

My second question then is how can I abstract this even more so that the unpacking is not specific to the `std::bitset` class?
Is there a way to modify the `Class1` template definition so that I can expand some arbitrary templated class that I develop instead of `std::bitset`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might write something like:

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... M>
class Class1 {
    template <template <typename, typename...> class C,
              template <std::size_t> class inner>
    using rebind_with_type = C<inner<N>, inner<M>...>;
};
```

And then

```
Class1<10, 20, 25>::rebind_with_type<Class2, std::bit_set>
// -> Class2<std::bit_set<10>, std::bit_set<20>, std::bit_set<25>>
```

And if call it with dependent name, don't forget `typename`/`template`:

```
typename Class1<N, M...>::template rebind_with_type<Class2, std::bit_set>
// -> Class2<std::bit_set<N>, std::bit_set<M>...>
```

Comment: For reference : [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter)

Answer (score 4):

I find you can think of the ... operator on parameter packs in this way:

```
f(g(Xs)...);
```

will expand to

```
f(g(Xs1), g(Xs2), ..., g(Xsn));
```

for any operations f and g. Really all it is doing is adding a comma seperated list of g applied to each of the parameters provided. The ... defines where it should begin the expansion
These operations can be for types or values, so in your case our f is Class2<...> and our g is std::bitset our type would look like

```
Class2<std::bitset<N>, std::bitset<M>...>
```

The first one needs to be explicitly added since it's not part of the parameter pack ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are excellent but let me give you an even more generic version of the accepted answer. You basically create a using alias that takes two templates, the first is the class that will hold the class templates as template parameters, and the second the template (like `bitset`) that you want to pass types to.

```
template<template<class...> class Y, template<class...> class Z, class... Ts>
using fold_types_into_t = Y<Z<Ts>...>;
template<template<class...> class Y, template<auto...> class Z, auto... Vs>
using fold_values_into_t = Y<Z<Vs>...>;

template<class,class...>
struct Class2;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... M>
class Class1 {
  // Class2<std::bitset<10>, std::bitset<20>, std::bitset<25>>
  using T=fold_values_into_t<Class2, std::bitset, N, M...>;
};
```

There could also be added support for classes that take values as well as types.